# How to access multiple column value in android sqlite application?

Tags: android

I am building an application where i need to access some details about the user that i stored in an sqlite database. The issue is that i am familiar with the code to return "just" a single value...but when i try to access more than one column..the application errors out.
Below is the code i am using.Thanks.

```
public String selectAll()
{

Cursor cursor = db.query(DB_TABLE_NAME2, new String[] {   DB_COLUMN_1_NAME,DB_COLUMN_2_NAME,DB_COLUMN_3_NAME,DB_COLUMN_4_NAME,DB_COLUMN_5_NAME,DB_COLUMN_6_NAME},null, null, null, null,null); 

  if(cursor.getCount() >0)
  {


      cursor.moveToNext();

          email = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN_1_NAME));
          password=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN_2_NAME));
           phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN_3_NAME));
           fname=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN_4_NAME));
           lname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN_5_NAME));
           location=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN_6_NAME));
           street = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB_COLUMN_7_NAME));

  }

           return password;
           return email;
           return phone;
           return fname;
           return lname;        

           return location;
           return street;
           return email;  


}
```

Comment: hi check your code. your query has only 6 columns but your trying to access 7 columns. So it will giver error.

Comment: Look at your code... it has a bunch of **return** statements. But it will exit at the very first one. So, it will always return the `password`, only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hiii

You can use Wrapper class having getter and setter method and simple add the values in setter method of particular variable.
By Passing the whole wrapper class you can get the values of all the  variables using getter method.

Hope u get what i say.....

Comment: avoid internal getter/setter method instead of this use public static member. see this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html

Comment: yeah i know abt that your answer was not wrong, ur absolutely right but as performance wise that thing I was told you

Answer (score 0):

Actually you didn't put loop in your code that's why its returning single column for multiple column make loop. example:

```
$if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            plysidvec[i] = c.getString(0);
            plysvec.add(c.getString(1));
            i++;
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
```